# com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not resolved in ApiFest

Tags: jdbc, maven-2

Here is what my pom.xml looks like :

```html
<dependency>
 <groupId>mysql</groupId>
 <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
 <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Code where i am trying to get jdbc connection :

```
 public static Connection getConnection() {
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String dbName = "dbname” ";
    String userName = "userName";
    String password = "password";
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);
        if (connection != null) {
            System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Inside exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Returning connection >>> " + connection);
    return connection;
}
```

I am running ApiFest server using command :

```css
java -Dproperties.file=apifest-oauth.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.xml -jar target/apifest-oauth20-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:789)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
```

Also tried downloading com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.jar and added it to class path but no help.

Comment: Without the full pom it is impossible to help...I assume you have put the dependency into a dependencyManagement part?

Comment: I suppose you build your own custom classes jar where you try to obtain a connection to mySql DB. If so - you need to create the custom jar with all its dependencies otherwise ApiFest server cannot load the jar successfully.